# Spring RabbitListener invoke a method after a message is sent

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

After a specific number of messages is processed by my sink I need to stop the Rabbit listener and invoke a method after which the listener is enabled again.

```
@RabbitListener(...)
public void sink(Message msg) {
    processMsg();

    if (condition) {
        rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.stop();
        doTask();
        rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.start();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the transaction will fail and the message will go back to the queue if I stop the listener inside of the sink method. I'm looking for a way to invoke a method after a transaction is complete and the listener isn't holding any messages.

> 1. Receive a msg and process the msg
> 2. Finish the transaction and release the msg   <- **I don't want to receive any new msgs after this point**
> 3. If the condition is satisfied stop the listener
> 4. Do a long running task
> 5. Start the listener

I can't move to the manual transaction management because it would require too many changes in my code and I can't hold any messages when my custom task is executed because it's a long running task and I want other workers to process the messages during this time.

`setAfterReceivePostProcessors` and `setAdviceChain` in the Rabbit factory configuration won't work in my case because in both cases the method will be invoked when the listener is holding a message.

Comment: What is the purpose of stopping and starting the container? If the container concurrency is 1, you will not receive any new messages until the listener exits.

Comment: @GaryRussell The task that I want to run after releasing a message runs for a long time and during this time I don't want to hold or receive any new messages.

Comment: You won't "hold or receive" any new messages if you set the prefetch to 1; but perhaps you shouldn't be using a listener container at all - see my answer.

Comment: @GaryRussell Prefetch won't help because I want to finish the transaction -> stop the listener -> run the task -> start the listener. I can't stop the listener at the end of the transaction because the message will be returned to the queue and it will cause other issues for me. I've seen your answer but I would prefer to find a workaround before making any drastic changes in the listener.

Comment: You are simply using the wrong technology for the task at hand - you are over complicating things. I can't help further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a message listener container is not the right approach for your application; you need a "pull" model instead.

You can use on of the `rabbitTemplate.receive()` or `receiveAndConvert()` methods to pull messages on-demand.

If you use them outside of a transaction, the message will be ack'd immediately; run it in a transaction if you want the message ack'd after your process completes.

Answer (score 1):

You can start a new thread if the condition satisfies which will stop the listener  and do some task and start the listener. Although it may not be guaranteed that new thread will stop the listener before any new message consumed by the original listener.But it can work approximately.

Instead of starting a thread manually, you can have a new queue where you can publish a message (like start/stop) and the new listener can stop the original listener when put an instruction message to the new queue like start or stop.

Second Approach :

You can try another approach I think it should work, instead of stopping listener setMaxConcurrentConsumers to 0, which should disable the listener not allowing it to consume any more message without stopping the listener.  And after doing your task change it to original value, I guess its 1 in your case.